# How to uninstall dev dependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I'm working on a project that depends on react-native-gifted-chat. I want to customize `react-native-gifted-chat` so I clone it. I do the change. I run`npm i; npm run build`. I use `watchman` to copy the files to my project's `node_modules`. I run my project, and I get an error about react versions not matching. I understand that react was installed in the `react-native-gifted-chat` clone. My thing is.. how do I uninstall it? I understand that `react` is in the `devDependencies` of `react-native-gifted-chat`, and I don't need it after doing the build. `npm prune --production` doesn't remove the devDependencies. How to remove them?

I am not looking for an answer like "Just do `npm uninstall react`". I am looking to uninstall all `devDependencies` as I do not need them anymore.

EDIT: OR! Maybe I just don't understand the flow of editing an npm package to my needs?

Comment: To remove a dev dependency, you need to attach the -D or --save-dev flag to the npm uninstall, and then specify the name of the package.

The basic syntax for doing this is npm uninstall -D package-name or npm uninstall --save-dev package-name

Comment: I specifically ask about removing all devDependencies, not one in particular

Comment: Or, I am asking for what's the workflow when modifying a dependency

Comment: I solved my problem by using yalc!